# Mac Catalina doesn't load links from WebBrowser when using loadstrings

Tags: macos, delphi, twebbrowser

I am trying to format my RSS feed and then load it into a FMX.WebBrowser using LoadStrings. The links I format work in Windows, but on macOS, the links don't open the browser to the post. It doesnt' do anything. If I load the Browser from a page, all links work within the browser fine. Here is the code. Is there a problem with Mac and WebBrowser.loadstrings?

```
XMLDocument1.XML.Text := sl.Text;
  XMLDocument1.Active := true;
  StartItemNode := XMLDocument1.DocumentElement.ChildNodes.First.ChildNodes.FindNode('item') ;
  ANode := StartItemNode;
  repeat
    STitle := ANode.ChildNodes['title'].Text;
    sLink := ANode.ChildNodes['link'].Text;
    //showmessage(sLink);
    //sLink := StringReplace(sLink,'https;//','',[rfReplaceAll]);
    sDesc := ANode.ChildNodes['description'].Text;
    i := Pos('</p>',sDesc,1)+4;
    sDesc := copy(sDesc,i,200);


    s := s + '<a href="'+sLink+'" target="_blank">'+sTitle+'</a>'+
    //s := s + '<h4><a href="&quot;'+sLink+'"><span style="font-family: verdana, geneva, sans-serif;">'+STitle+'</span></a></h4>'+
    '<p>'+sDesc+'</p>';
//    showmessage(slink);
    ANode := ANode.NextSibling;
  until ANode = nil;
  WebBrowser2.LoadFromStrings(s,'about:blank');
```

Any ideas?

Comment: RSS Feeds? Did I fall into a time machine or something? All the major players have removed support for RSS long, long ago (except for Internet Explorer, which is always far behind on time).

Comment: As you can see from the code, I am parsing the feed into a simple HTML file. It could be any <a> link that fails on a mac if loaded from loadStrings Maybe mac won't honor the links because it is not a complete formatted page with an HTML tag, and body tag, but Windows doesn't care. I will try that.

Comment: RSS aside, FWIW, it's not an OS level thing. It's a browser level thing. You should always format any HTML page according to HTML standards - especially if you want it to work in more than one browser. The `TWebBrowser` control isn't its own browser - it just wraps the main browser on whatever OS you're using. For example, on Windows, that would be Internet Explorer.

Comment: I agree with  Jerry Dodge, so I added all the basic HTML page stuff (<head><body>), just the basic starter page and added my links and descriptions I received from the XMLDocument component, wrapping them in <p>'s, and loaded the string with LoadStrings. When clicked, the links lanch the browser (outside of the software) correctly, bring up Explorer on Windows. But nothing on the mac 64-bit version. Now, if I load a page normally with navigate, all is fine on both 64-bit platforms. But I want to display just a working HTML active document. Are there permissions issues with mac Catalina?